# How to use OpenACC for integrating differential equations?

Tags: c++, openacc

I'm trying to use OpenACC to compute a physical system with various initial conditions. I only have 2 loops, the first one contains the initial conditions and the second one integrates the equations of motion. I tried this

```
#pragma acc parallel loop copyout(X1,X2,Y1,Y2)

for(int j=0;j<nx;j++){ 

t= 0.;      

x2 = x2_ini+abs(x2_ini-x2_fin)*j/nx;     
y2= 0.;

px2 = 0.;
py2 = L/x2;


x1 = X1_neg(x2);  
y1 = 0.;

px1= 0.;
py1 = 0.;

#pragma acc loop seq

for(int i=0;i<n0;i++){      


    if(i%5==0){

        X1[j][i/5]=x1;
        Y1[j][i/5]=y1;
        X2[j][i/5]=x2;
        Y2[j][i/5]=y2;

    }


    if(x1>=0){
        Qpos(Q1, Q2, x1, y1);
        }else
        Qneg(Q1, Q2, x1, y1);

    if(x2>=0){
        Qpos(Q3, Q4, x2, y2);
        }else
        Qneg(Q3, Q4, x2, y2);

    P1=2.*(px1*Q1+py1*Q2);
    P2=2.*(py1*Q1-px1*Q2);
    P3=2.*(px2*Q3+py2*Q4);
    P4=2.*(py2*Q3-px2*Q4);
    R(R1,Q1,Q2);
    R(R2,Q3,Q4);
    Energ(E,x1,x2,y1,y2,px1,px2,py1,py2); 

    V1=(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*P1/4.;
    V2=(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*P2/4.;
    V3=(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*P3/4.;
    V4=(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*P4/4.;

    r_12(r12,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4);
    dr_12(dr12,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4);

    //

    A1=A_1(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V3,V4,r12,E);
    A2=A_2(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V2,V3,V4,r12,E);
    A3=A_3(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,r12,E);
    A4=A_4(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V4,r12,E); 
    J1=J_1(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A3,A4,r12,dr12,E);
    J2=J_2(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A3,A4,r12,dr12,E);
    J3=J_3(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A1,A2,r12,dr12,E);
    J4=J_4(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A1,A2,r12,dr12,E);

    dTao(dtao,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A1,A2,A3,A4,J1,J2,J3,J4);

    Q1_=Q_pred(Q1,V1,A1,J1,dtao);
    Q2_=Q_pred(Q2,V2,A2,J2,dtao);
    Q3_=Q_pred(Q3,V3,A3,J3,dtao);
    Q4_=Q_pred(Q4,V4,A4,J4,dtao);       
    V1_=V_pred(V1,A1,J1,dtao);
    V2_=V_pred(V2,A2,J2,dtao);
    V3_=V_pred(V3,A3,J3,dtao);
    V4_=V_pred(V4,A4,J4,dtao);

    r_12(r12_,Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_);
    dr_12(dr12_,Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_);

    A1_=A_1(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V3_,V4_,r12_,E);
    A2_=A_2(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V2_,V3_,V4_,r12_,E);
    A3_=A_3(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,r12_,E);
    A4_=A_4(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V4_,r12_,E);    
    J1_=J_1(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_,A3_,A4_,r12_,dr12_,E);
    J2_=J_2(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_,A3_,A4_,r12_,dr12_,E);
    J3_=J_3(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_,A1_,A2_,r12_,dr12_,E);
    J4_=J_4(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_,A1_,A2_,r12_,dr12_,E);  

    //


    V1_=V1+(A1_+A1)*dtao/2.-(J1_-J1)*dtao*dtao/12.;
    V2_=V2+(A2_+A2)*dtao/2.-(J2_-J2)*dtao*dtao/12.;
    V3_=V3+(A3_+A3)*dtao/2.-(J3_-J3)*dtao*dtao/12.;
    V4_=V4+(A4_+A4)*dtao/2.-(J4_-J4)*dtao*dtao/12.; 

    Q1_=Q1+(V1_+V1)*dtao/2.-(A1_-A1)*dtao*dtao/10.+(J1_+J1)*dtao*dtao*dtao/120.;
    Q2_=Q2+(V2_+V2)*dtao/2.-(A2_-A2)*dtao*dtao/10.+(J2_+J2)*dtao*dtao*dtao/120.;
    Q3_=Q3+(V3_+V3)*dtao/2.-(A3_-A3)*dtao*dtao/10.+(J3_+J3)*dtao*dtao*dtao/120.;   
    Q4_=Q4+(V4_+V4)*dtao/2.-(A4_-A4)*dtao*dtao/10.+(J4_+J4)*dtao*dtao*dtao/120.;

    Q1=Q1_;
    Q2=Q2_;
    Q3=Q3_;
    Q4=Q4_;
    V1=V1_;
    V2=V2_;
    V3=V3_;
    V4=V4_;

    P1=4.*V1/(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4);
    P2=4.*V2/(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4);
    P3=4.*V3/(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2);
    P4=4.*V4/(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2);

    dt=R1*R1*R2*R2*dtao;
    t=t+dt;

    x1=Q1*Q1-Q2*Q2;
    x2=Q3*Q3-Q4*Q4;
    y1=2.*Q1*Q2;
    y2=2.*Q3*Q4;

    px1=(Q1*P1-Q2*P2)/(2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2));
    py1=(Q2*P1+Q1*P2)/(2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2));
    px2=(Q3*P3-Q4*P4)/(2.*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4));
    py2=(Q4*P3+Q3*P4)/(2.*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4));



    }



}
```

but when compiling using `pgc++ -acc code.cpp -Minfo=accel -ta=tesla:cuda9.2`, I receive a lot of errors so I suspect I'm not doing much correctly. All the information I need is stored in the X and Y arrays. With every initial condition set I define new variables **Q**,**V**,**A**,**J**,**P**,... which are mostly changed with functions and at the end of the second loop the new values of `x1,y1,x2,y2` in the next time step are set and then repeats.

What do I need to change to be able to compile the code? I would also want to know if there is any other possible way to extract the information (e.g. pointers or printing the values in a file) since I am not sure if it's allowed while parallelizing and normal arrays can't store a lot of information.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete reproducing example?  If not, can you describe the errors?  It may be something simple like missing the array shapes for the X and Y arrays, or missing device version of your called subroutines.

Comment: I've linked the full reproducing example with a small modification in the way the information was stored and printed, I hope this isn't a mayor issue when compiling.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qmBDfFYCZ40ILo-wO8f9SfEpBOdsVEwr/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues going on.

First, you can't perform string operation or file I/O from the device.  This was missing from your original code snip-it.  You'll need to rethink how you store your results to the file.  For now, I just disabled it via a macro when OpenACC is used.

Second, you're using vectors.  Vectors can be used, but are problematic.  They aren't thread-safe and are really a class with three pointers.  Data clause perform shallow copies, so would only copy the pointers, not the data they point to.  While tricky, you can perform a manual deep copy or use CUDA Unified Memory (-ta=tesla:managed), but I just made them regular allocated arrays since you don't really need them to be vectors.

Finally, your performance will be very poor.  "nx" is only 10, so the code severely under utilizes the device.  You'll want nx to be in the thousands, or hundreds of thousands, to see real benefit from a GPU.

Also, your register usage is quite high due to use of significant number of local variables.  High register usage leads to low occupancy, which can often result in lower performance.  Though the only way to help with this would be to break the large loop into several small loops, storing the intermediate results in global arrays.  Though, you may need to do something similar anyway to handle the file I/O issue.

```
% cat pcc.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
#include<ctime>
#include<vector>

//Compile using  pgc++ -acc pcc.cpp -Minfo=accel -ta=tesla:cuda9.2

using namespace std;
typedef std::vector<double> RealVector;

double Q_pred(double,double,double,double,double);
double V_pred(double,double,double,double);
double A_1(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
double A_2(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
double A_3(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
double A_4(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
double J_1(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double, double,double);
double J_2(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double, double,double);
double J_3(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double, double,double);
double J_4(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double, double,double);
void Qpos(double&,double&,double,double);
void Qneg(double&,double&,double,double);
void R(double&,double,double);
void Energ(double&,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
void r_12(double&,double,double,double,double);
void dr_12(double&,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
void dTao(double&,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
double X1_pos(double,double);
double X1_neg(double,double);


int main(){

        int n0,nx,N,fac;
        double x1,x2,y1,y2,x2_ini,x2_fin;
        double px1,px2,py1,py2;
        double Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4;
        double V1,V2,V3,V4;
        double A1,A2,A3,A4;
        double J1,J2,J3,J4;
        double Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_;
        double V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_;
        double A1_,A2_,A3_,A4_;
        double J1_,J2_,J3_,J4_;
        double P1,P2,P3,P4;
        double dtao,R1,R2,r12,dr12,r12_,dr12_;
        double dt,t,E,L;
        ofstream points,graph;
        ofstream electron1,electron2;
        string x20;

        nx = 10;
        n0 = 2097152;
        N = 262144;
        fac=n0/N;

        x2_ini = 7.824;
        x2_fin = 10.;
        L = 0.28284271247461900976;

//      RealVector X1(N),Y1(N),X2(N),Y2(N),T(N),T_(N);
        double *X1 = new double[N];
        double *Y1 = new double[N];
        double *X2 = new double[N];
        double *Y2 = new double[N];
        double *T = new double[N];
        double *T_ = new double[N];

#pragma acc parallel loop copyout(X1[:N],X2[:N],Y1[:N],Y2[:N],T[:N],T_[:N])
        for(int j=0;j<nx;j++){
                t= 0.;
                x2 = x2_ini+abs(x2_ini-x2_fin)*j/(nx-1);
                y2= 0.;

                px2 = 0.;
                py2 = L/x2;

                x1 = X1_neg(x2,L);
                y1 = 0.;
                px1= 0.;
                py1 = 0.;
#ifndef _OPENACC
                x20=to_string(x2);
#endif

#pragma acc loop seq
                for(int i=0;i<n0;i++){
                        if(i%fac==0){
                                T[i/fac]=t;
                                X1[i/fac]=x1;
                                Y1[i/fac]=y1;
                                X2[i/fac]=x2;
                                Y2[i/fac]=y2;
                        }

                        if(x1>=0){
                                Qpos(Q1, Q2, x1, y1);
                        }else
                                Qneg(Q1, Q2, x1, y1);

                        if(x2>=0){
                                Qpos(Q3, Q4, x2, y2);
                        }else
                                Qneg(Q3, Q4, x2, y2);

                        P1=2.*(px1*Q1+py1*Q2);
                        P2=2.*(py1*Q1-px1*Q2);
                        P3=2.*(px2*Q3+py2*Q4);
                        P4=2.*(py2*Q3-px2*Q4);
                        R(R1,Q1,Q2);
                        R(R2,Q3,Q4);
                        Energ(E,x1,x2,y1,y2,px1,px2,py1,py2);

                        V1=(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*P1/4.;
                        V2=(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*P2/4.;
                        V3=(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*P3/4.;
                        V4=(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*P4/4.;

                        r_12(r12,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4);
                        dr_12(dr12,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4);

                        //

                        A1=A_1(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V3,V4,r12,E);
                        A2=A_2(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V2,V3,V4,r12,E);
                        A3=A_3(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,r12,E);
                        A4=A_4(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V4,r12,E);
                        J1=J_1(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A3,A4,r12,dr12,E);
                        J2=J_2(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A3,A4,r12,dr12,E);
                        J3=J_3(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A1,A2,r12,dr12,E);
                        J4=J_4(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A1,A2,r12,dr12,E);

                        dTao(dtao,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,V1,V2,V3,V4,A1,A2,A3,A4,J1,J2,J3,J4);

                        Q1_=Q_pred(Q1,V1,A1,J1,dtao);
                        Q2_=Q_pred(Q2,V2,A2,J2,dtao);
                        Q3_=Q_pred(Q3,V3,A3,J3,dtao);
                        Q4_=Q_pred(Q4,V4,A4,J4,dtao);
                        V1_=V_pred(V1,A1,J1,dtao);
                        V2_=V_pred(V2,A2,J2,dtao);
                        V3_=V_pred(V3,A3,J3,dtao);
                        V4_=V_pred(V4,A4,J4,dtao);

                        r_12(r12_,Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_);
                        dr_12(dr12_,Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_);

                        A1_=A_1(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V3_,V4_,r12_,E);
                        A2_=A_2(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V2_,V3_,V4_,r12_,E);
                        A3_=A_3(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,r12_,E);
                        A4_=A_4(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V4_,r12_,E);
                        J1_=J_1(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_,A3_,A4_,r12_,dr12_,E);
                        J2_=J_2(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_,A3_,A4_,r12_,dr12_,E);
                        J3_=J_3(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_,A1_,A2_,r12_,dr12_,E);
                        J4_=J_4(Q1_,Q2_,Q3_,Q4_,V1_,V2_,V3_,V4_,A1_,A2_,r12_,dr12_,E);

                        //


                        V1_=V1+(A1_+A1)*dtao/2.-(J1_-J1)*dtao*dtao/12.;
                        V2_=V2+(A2_+A2)*dtao/2.-(J2_-J2)*dtao*dtao/12.;
                        V3_=V3+(A3_+A3)*dtao/2.-(J3_-J3)*dtao*dtao/12.;
                        V4_=V4+(A4_+A4)*dtao/2.-(J4_-J4)*dtao*dtao/12.;

                        Q1_=Q1+(V1_+V1)*dtao/2.-(A1_-A1)*dtao*dtao/10.+(J1_+J1)*dtao*dtao*dtao/120.;
                        Q2_=Q2+(V2_+V2)*dtao/2.-(A2_-A2)*dtao*dtao/10.+(J2_+J2)*dtao*dtao*dtao/120.;
                        Q3_=Q3+(V3_+V3)*dtao/2.-(A3_-A3)*dtao*dtao/10.+(J3_+J3)*dtao*dtao*dtao/120.;
                        Q4_=Q4+(V4_+V4)*dtao/2.-(A4_-A4)*dtao*dtao/10.+(J4_+J4)*dtao*dtao*dtao/120.;

                        Q1=Q1_;
                        Q2=Q2_;
                        Q3=Q3_;
                        Q4=Q4_;
                        V1=V1_;
                        V2=V2_;
                        V3=V3_;
                        V4=V4_;

                        P1=4.*V1/(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4);
                        P2=4.*V2/(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4);
                        P3=4.*V3/(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2);
                        P4=4.*V4/(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2);

                        dt=R1*R1*R2*R2*dtao;
                        t=t+dt;

                        x1=Q1*Q1-Q2*Q2;
                        x2=Q3*Q3-Q4*Q4;
                        y1=2.*Q1*Q2;
                        y2=2.*Q3*Q4;

                        px1=(Q1*P1-Q2*P2)/(2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2));
                        py1=(Q2*P1+Q1*P2)/(2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2));
                        px2=(Q3*P3-Q4*P4)/(2.*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4));
                        py2=(Q4*P3+Q3*P4)/(2.*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4));



                }

                dt=t/(N-1);

#ifndef _OPENACC
                for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
                        T_[i]=i*dt;

                electron1.open(("electron1_neg_x20_"+x20+".dat").c_str());
                electron2.open(("electron2_neg_x20_"+x20+".dat").c_str());

                for(int i=0; i<N ;i++){

                        electron1<<T_[i]<<" "<<X1[i]<<" "<<Y1[i]<<endl;
                        electron2<<T_[i]<<" "<<X2[i]<<" "<<Y2[i]<<endl;

                }

                electron1.close();
                electron2.close();
#endif

        }

        delete [] X1;
        delete [] X2;
        delete [] Y1;
        delete [] Y2;
        delete [] T;
        delete [] T_;

        return 0;

}

double Q_pred(double Q, double V, double A, double J, double dtao){
        return Q+V*dtao+A*dtao*dtao/2.+J*dtao*dtao*dtao/6.;
}

double V_pred(double V, double A, double J, double dtao){
        return V+A*dtao+J*dtao*dtao/2.;
}

double A_1(double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4, double V1, double V3, double V4,double r12, double E){
        return 2.*(Q3*V3+Q4*V4)*V1/(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)+(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*(-(4.*Q1*(V3*V3+V4*V4)/pow(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2,2.)-4.*Q1+2.*Q1*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*(-E+1./r12)-2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*((Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*Q1+(Q4*Q4-Q3*Q3)*Q1-2.*Q2*Q3*Q4)/pow(r12,3.)))/4.;
}

double A_2(double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4, double V2, double V3, double V4,double r12, double E){
        return 2.*(Q3*V3+Q4*V4)*V2/(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)+(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*(-4.*Q2*(V3*V3+V4*V4)/pow(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2,2.)+4.*Q2-2.*Q2*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*(-E+1./r12)+2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*((Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*Q2-(Q4*Q4-Q3*Q3)*Q2-2.*Q1*Q3*Q4)/pow(r12,3.))/4.;
}

double A_3(double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4, double V1, double V2, double V3,double r12, double E){
        return 2.*(Q1*V1+Q2*V2)*V3/(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)+(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(-4.*Q3*(V1*V1+V2*V2)/pow(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4,2.)+4.*Q3-2.*Q3*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(-E+1./r12)+2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*((Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*Q3+(Q2*Q2-Q1*Q1)*Q3-2.*Q1*Q2*Q4)/pow(r12,3.))/4.;
}

double A_4(double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4, double V1, double V2, double V4,double r12, double E){
        return 2.*(Q1*V1+Q2*V2)*V4/(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)+(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(-4.*Q4*(V1*V1+V2*V2)/pow(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4,2.)+4.*Q4-2.*Q4*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(-E+1./r12)+2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*((Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*Q4-(Q2*Q2-Q1*Q1)*Q4-2.*Q1*Q2*Q3)/pow(r12,3.))/4.;
}

double J_1(double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4, double V1,double V2, double V3, double V4, double A3, double A4, double r12,double dr12 ,double E){
        return 2.*(V3*V3+V4*V4+Q3*A3+Q4*A4)*V1/(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)+(Q3*V3+Q4*V4)*(-(4.*Q1*(V3*V3+V4*V4)/pow(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2,2.)-4.*Q1+2.*Q1*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*(-E+1./r12)-2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*((Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*Q1+(Q4*Q4-Q3*Q3)*Q1-2.*Q2*Q3*Q4)/pow(r12,3.)))+(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*(4 *(V1 - ((V3*V3 + V4*V4) *V1)/pow(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2,2.) + (4 *Q1 *(V3*V3 + V4*V4) *(Q1 *V1 + Q2 *V2))/pow(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2,3.) - (2 *Q1 *(V3 *A3 + V4 *A4))/pow(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2,2.))+(1./(r12*r12))*(2 *r12 *(-1 + E *r12) *(Q3*Q3 *V1 +2 *Q1 *Q3 *V3 + Q4 *(Q4 *V1 + 2 *Q1 *V4)) + 2 *Q1 *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4)* dr12)+ (1./(pow(r12,4)))*2 *(2 *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *(Q1*Q1*Q1 - 2 *Q2 *Q3 *Q4 + Q1 *(Q2*Q2 - Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4)) *r12 *(Q1 *V1 + Q2 *V2) + 2 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q1*Q1*Q1 - 2 *Q2 *Q3 *Q4 + Q1 *(Q2*Q2 - Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4)) *r12 *(Q3 *V3 + Q4 *V4) + (Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *r12 *(3 *Q1*Q1 *V1 + Q2*Q2 *V1 + (-Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *V1 - 2 *Q3 *Q4 *V2 - 2 *Q2 *(Q4 *V3 + Q3 *V4) + 2 *Q1 *(Q2 *V2 - Q3 *V3 + Q4 *V4)) - 3 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *(Q1*Q1*Q1 - 2 *Q2 *Q3 *Q4 + Q1 *(Q2*Q2 - Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4))* dr12))/4.;
}

double J_2(double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4, double V1,double V2, double V3, double V4, double A3, double A4, double r12,double dr12 , double E){
        return 2.*(V3*V3+V4*V4+Q3*A3+Q4*A4)*V2/(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)+(Q3*V3+Q4*V4)*(-(4.*Q2*(V3*V3+V4*V4)/pow(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2,2.)-4.*Q2+2.*Q2*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*(-E+1./r12)-2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*((Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*Q2-(Q4*Q4-Q3*Q3)*Q2-2.*Q1*Q3*Q4)/pow(r12,3.)))+(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*(4 *(V2 - ((V3*V3 + V4*V4) *V2)/pow(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2,2.) + (4 *Q2 *(V3*V3 + V4*V4) *(Q1 *V1 + Q2 *V2))/pow(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2,3.) - ( 2 *Q2 *(V3 *A3 + V4 *A4))/pow(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2,2.))+(1./(r12*r12))*(2 *r12 *(-1 + E *r12) *(Q3*Q3 *V2 + 2 *Q2 *Q3 *V3 + Q4 *(Q4 *V2 + 2 *Q2 *V4)) + 2 *Q2 *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *dr12) + (1./(pow(r12,4)))*2 *(2 *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *(Q2 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3) - 2 *Q1 *Q3 *Q4 - Q2 *Q4*Q4) *r12 *(Q1 *V1 + Q2 *V2) + 2 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q2 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3) -2 *Q1 *Q3 *Q4 - Q2 *Q4*Q4) *r12 *(Q3 *V3 + Q4 *V4) + (Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *r12 *(Q1*Q1 *V2 + Q3*Q3 *V2 + (3 *Q2*Q2 - Q4*Q4) *V2 +Q3 *(-2 *Q4 *V1 + 2 *Q2 *V3) -2 *Q2 *Q4 *V4 + 2 *Q1 *(Q2 *V1 - Q4 *V3 - Q3 *V4)) - 3 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *(Q2 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3) - 2 *Q1 *Q3 *Q4 - Q2 *Q4*Q4)* dr12))/4.;
}

double J_3(double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4, double V1,double V2, double V3, double V4, double A1, double A2, double r12,double dr12 , double E){
        return 2.*(V1*V1+V2*V2+Q1*A1+Q2*A2)*V3/(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)+(Q1*V1+Q2*V2)*(-(4.*Q3*(V1*V1+V2*V2)/pow(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4,2.)-4.*Q3+2.*Q3*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(-E+1./r12)-2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*((Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*Q3+(Q2*Q2-Q1*Q1)*Q3-2.*Q1*Q2*Q4)/pow(r12,3.)))+(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(4 *(V3 - ((V1*V1 + V2*V2) *V3)/pow(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4,2.) + (4 *Q3 *(V1*V1 + V2*V2) *(Q3 *V3 + Q4 *V4))/pow(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4,3.) - (2 *Q3 *(V1 *A1 + V2 *A2))/pow(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4,2.))+  (1./(r12*r12))*(2 *r12 *(-1 + E *r12) *(2 *Q3 *(Q1 *V1 + Q2 *V2) + (Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *V3) + 2 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *Q3 *dr12) + (1./(pow(r12,4.)))*2 *(2 *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *(-Q1*Q1 *Q3 - 2 *Q1 *Q2 *Q4 + Q3 *(Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4)) *r12 *(Q1 *V1 + Q2 *V2) + 2 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(-Q1*Q1 *Q3 - 2 *Q1 *Q2 *Q4 + Q3 *(Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4)) *r12 *(Q3 *V3 + Q4 *V4) + (Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *r12 *(Q2 *(-2 *Q4 *V1 + 2 *Q3 *V2) - Q1*Q1 *V3 + Q2*Q2 *V3 + (3 *Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *V3 + 2 *Q3 *Q4 *V4 - 2 *Q1 *(Q3 *V1 + Q4 *V2 + Q2 *V4)) - 3 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *(-Q1*Q1 *Q3 - 2 *Q1 *Q2 *Q4 + Q3 *(Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4)) *dr12))/4.;
}

double J_4(double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4, double V1,double V2, double V3, double V4, double A1, double A2, double r12,double dr12 , double E){
        return 2.*(V1*V1+V2*V2+Q1*A1+Q2*A2)*V4/(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)+(Q1*V1+Q2*V2)*(-(4.*Q4*(V1*V1+V2*V2)/pow(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4,2.)-4.*Q4+2.*Q4*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(-E+1./r12)-2.*(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*((Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4)*Q4-(Q2*Q2-Q1*Q1)*Q4-2.*Q1*Q2*Q3)/pow(r12,3.)))+(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2)*(4 *(V4 - ((V1*V1 + V2*V2) *V4)/pow(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4,2.) + (4 *Q4 *(V1*V1 + V2*V2) *(Q3 *V3 + Q4 *V4))/pow(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4,3.) - ( 2 *Q4 *(V1 *A1 + V2 *A2))/pow(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4,2.))+ (1./(r12*r12))*(-2 *r12 *(-1 + E* r12) *(2 *Q4 *(Q1 *V1 + Q2 *V2) + (Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *V4) - 2 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *Q4 *dr12) + (1./(pow(r12,4)))*2 *(2 *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *(-2 *Q1 *Q2 *Q3 + (Q1*Q1 - Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3) *Q4 + Q4*Q4*Q4) *r12 *(Q1 *V1 + Q2 *V2) + 2 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(-2 *Q1 *Q2 *Q3 + (Q1*Q1 - Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3) *Q4 + Q4*Q4*Q4) *r12 *(Q3 *V3 + Q4 *V4) + (Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *r12 *(2 *Q1 *(Q4 *V1 -Q3 *V2) + 2 *Q3 *Q4 *V3 - 2 *Q2 *(Q3 *V1 +Q4 *V2 + Q1 *V3) + (Q1*Q1 - Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3 + 3 *Q4*Q4) *V4) - 3 *(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2) *(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4) *(-2 *Q1 *Q2 *Q3 + (Q1*Q1 - Q2*Q2 + Q3*Q3) *Q4 + Q4*Q4*Q4) *dr12))/4.;
}



void Qpos(double& Qx, double& Qy, double x, double y){
        Qx=pow(0.5*(pow(x*x+y*y,0.5)+x),0.5);
        Qy=y/(2.*pow(0.5*(pow(x*x+y*y,0.5)+x),0.5));
        return;
}

void Qneg(double& Qx, double& Qy, double x, double y){
        Qy=pow(0.5*(pow(x*x+y*y,0.5)-x),0.5);
        Qx=y/(2.*pow(0.5*(pow(x*x+y*y,0.5)-x),0.5));
        return;
}

void R(double& Ri, double Qx, double Qy){
        Ri=pow(Qx*Qx+Qy*Qy,0.5);
        return;
}

void Energ(double& E, double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2, double px1, double px2, double py1, double py2){
        E=(px1*px1+py1*py1)/2.+(px2*px2+py2*py2)/2.-2./pow(x1*x1+y1*y1,0.5)-2./pow(x2*x2+y2*y2,0.5)+1./pow(pow(x1-x2,2.)+pow(y1-y2,2.),0.5);
        return;
}



void r_12(double& r12,double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4){

        r12=pow(pow(Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2,2.)+pow(Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4,2.)-2.*pow(Q1*Q3+Q2*Q4,2.)+2.*pow(Q1*Q4-Q2*Q3,2.),0.5);

        return;
}

void dr_12(double& dr12,double Q1, double Q2, double Q3, double Q4, double V1,double V2, double V3, double V4){

        dr12=(2.*((Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2)*(Q1 *V1 + Q2 *V2) + (Q2 *Q3 - Q1 *Q4) *(-Q4 *V1 + Q3 *V2 + Q2 *V3 - Q1 *V4) - (Q1 *Q3 + Q2 *Q4) *(Q3 *V1 + Q4 *V2 + Q1 *V3 + Q2 *V4) + (Q3*Q3 +Q4*Q4) *(Q3 *V3 + Q4 *V4)))/pow(pow(Q1*Q1 + Q2*Q2,2) + 2*pow(Q2 *Q3 - Q1 *Q4,2.) -2 *pow(Q1 *Q3 + Q2 *Q4,2.) + pow(Q3*Q3 + Q4*Q4,2.),0.5);

        return;
}

void dTao(double& dtao,double Q1,double Q2,double Q3,double Q4,double V1,double V2,double V3,double V4,double A1,double A2,double A3,double A4,double J1,double J2,double J3,double J4){

        double modQ=Q1*Q1+Q2*Q2+Q3*Q3+Q4*Q4;
        double modV=V1*V1+V2*V2+V3*V3+V4*V4;
        double modA=A1*A1+A2*A2+A3*A3+A4*A4;
        double modJ=J1*J1+J2*J2+J3*J3+J4*J4;

        dtao=pow(0.0000001*(modA*modQ+modV*modV)/(modJ*modV+modA*modA),0.5);

        return;
}

double X1_pos(double x2, double L){

        return (-2. + L*L/x2 + 2.*x2 + pow(L*L*L*L - 20.*L*L*x2 + 68.*x2*x2 + 4.*L*L *x2*x2 - 40.*x2*x2*x2 + 4. *x2*x2*x2*x2,0.5)/x2)/(2.*(2.+ L*L/(x2*x2) - 4./x2));

}

double X1_neg(double x2, double L){

        return (-2. + L*L/x2 + 2.*x2 - pow(L*L*L*L - 20.*L*L*x2 + 68.*x2*x2 + 4.*L*L *x2*x2 - 40.*x2*x2*x2 + 4. *x2*x2*x2*x2,0.5)/x2)/(2.*(2.+ L*L/(x2*x2) - 4./x2));

}

% pgc++ -ta=tesla -Minfo=accel pcc.cpp -o pcc.exe ; ./pcc.exe
main:
     74, Generating copyout(T_[:N],X1[:N],X2[:N],Y2[:N],Y1[:N],T[:N])
         Generating Tesla code
         77, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(10) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
         94, #pragma acc loop seq
     94, Complex loop carried dependence of T->,X1-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried dependence of T-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried backward dependence of T-> prevents vectorization
         Complex loop carried dependence of Y1-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried dependence of X2-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried backward dependence of X2-> prevents vectorization
         Complex loop carried dependence of X2-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried dependence of X1-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried backward dependence of X1-> prevents vectorization
         Loop carried dependence of Y2->,Y1-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried backward dependence of Y2->,Y1-> prevents vectorization
         Complex loop carried dependence of Y2-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried scalar dependence for y2 at line 111
         Loop carried scalar dependence for py1 at line 113
         Loop carried scalar dependence for py2 at line 116
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q4 at line 122
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q2 at line 123,124
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q4 at line 126,127,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,140,145
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q1 at line 113,114,117,123,124,126,127,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,140,142,171
         Loop carried scalar dependence for py1 at line 114
         Loop carried scalar dependence for py2 at line 115
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q2 at line 117
         Loop carried scalar dependence for y2 at line 119
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q4 at line 121
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q2 at line 126,127,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,140,143,172
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q3 at line 115,116,118,121,122,126,127,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,140,144
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q4 at line 174
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q3 at line 173
         Loop carried scalar dependence for t at line 96
         Loop carried scalar dependence for y2 at line 100
         Loop carried scalar dependence for x1 at line 103
         Loop carried scalar dependence for y1 at line 104
         Loop carried scalar dependence for py2 at line 119
         Loop carried scalar dependence for y1 at line 98,106
         Loop carried scalar dependence for x2 at line 108
         Loop carried scalar dependence for y2 at line 109
         Loop carried scalar dependence for x1 at line 119,97,104,106
         Loop carried scalar dependence for x2 at line 119,99,109,111
         Loop carried scalar dependence for y1 at line 119
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q2 at line 113,114
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q4 at line 118
         Loop carried scalar dependence for px1 at line 113,114
         Loop carried scalar dependence for px2 at line 119
         Loop carried scalar dependence for Q4 at line 115,116
         Loop carried scalar dependence for px1 at line 119
         Loop carried scalar dependence for px2 at line 115,116
         Loop carried scalar dependence for py1 at line 119
Q_pred(double, double, double, double, double):
    240, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
V_pred(double, double, double, double):
    244, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
A_1(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    248, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
A_2(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    252, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
A_3(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    256, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
A_4(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    260, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
J_1(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    264, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
J_2(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    268, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
J_3(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    272, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
J_4(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    276, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
Qpos(double &, double &, double, double):
    282, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
Qneg(double &, double &, double, double):
    288, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
R(double &, double, double):
    294, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
Energ(double &, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    299, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
r_12(double &, double, double, double, double):
    306, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
dr_12(double &, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    313, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
dTao(double &, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double):
    320, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
X1_neg(double, double):
    338, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
std::abs(double):
      1, include "iostream"
          35, include "iostream"
                4, include "ostream"
                    38, include "ios"
                         42, include "ios_base.h"
                              41, include "locale_classes.h"
                                   40, include "string"
                                        52, include "basic_string.h"
                                           6391, include "string_conversions.h"
                                                  41, include "cstdlib"
                                                       77, include "std_abs.h"
                                                            71, Generating implicit acc routine seq
                                                                Generating acc routine seq
                                                                Generating Tesla code
__gnu_cxx::__promote_2<T1, T2, __gnu_cxx::__promote<T1, std::__is_integer<T1>::__value>::__type, __gnu_cxx::__promote<T2, std::__is_integer<T2>::__value>::__type>::__type std::pow<double, int>(T1, T2):
      2, include "math.h"
          59, include "math.h"
               36, include "cmath"
                   416, Generating implicit acc routine seq
                        Generating acc routine seq
                        Generating Tesla code

Accelerator Kernel Timing data
pcc.cpp
  main  NVIDIA  devicenum=0
    time(us): 35,476,363
    74: compute region reached 1 time
        74: kernel launched 1 time
            grid: [1]  block: [10]
             device time(us): total=35,475,345 max=35,475,345 min=35,475,345 avg=35,475,345
            elapsed time(us): total=35,475,684 max=35,475,684 min=35,475,684 avg=35,475,684
    74: data region reached 2 times
        227: data copyout transfers: 6
             device time(us): total=1,018 max=186 min=166 avg=169
```